# C#でタブにwebbrowserを追加することはできましたが操作が分かりません。

Tags: c#

例えば２番目のタブに表示されているwebbrowserを扱うには
どのように指定すれば良いのでしょうか？

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tabpage = new TabPage();
        tabpage.Text = "New File";
        tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabpage);
        WebBrowser webbrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webbrowser.Parent = tabpage;
        webbrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        webbrowser.Navigate("www.google.com");            
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Controls`プロパティを参照し、得られたコントロールをキャストすればよいです。

```
TabPage tabpage = (TabPage)tabControl1.Controls[1];
WebBrowser webbrowser = (WebBrowser)tabpage.Controls[0];
```

Comment: 無事コントロールできました！ありがとうございます。